# Converting to bases gives reversed output. How to make it correct without strrev?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, recursion

I came up with two slightly different approaches: one uses recursion and another one doesn't.

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;

void No_Recursion(ull num, char *str, int base, char *alpha){
    while (num){
        *(str++)=alpha[(num-1)%base];
        num=(num-1)/base;
    }
}

void Recursion(ull num, char *str, int base, char*alpha) {
    if (!num) return;
    *str=alpha[(num-1)%base];
    Recursion((num-1)/base,str+1,base,alpha);
}
```

These two functions are called similarly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define t 1000 // number of numbers to convert

int main (void) {
    char *s=calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    char al[]="abc";
    ull e;
    int base=strlen(al);

    for (e=1;e<=t;++e) {
        Recursion(e,s,base,al); // or the same with No_Recursion
        printf("%s\n",s);
    }

    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives output in reversed order:

```
a
b
c
aa
ba 
ca
ab
bb
cb
ac
... etc
```

I searched the Net and found out that this can be solved using the recursive algorithm. They suggested printing the digits after a recursive call. However, this didn't work for me. Moreover, `No_Recursion` seems to be a bit faster. Certainly, I can use `strrev` to reverse the resulting string, but it takes much time.

**Note**: yes, I'm using `(num-1)%base` and it's correct for my task, please don't say I need to use `num%base`.

**Note**: the alphabets may be absolutely random, not in alphabetical order

**The most important thing**: *I don't know the size of the resulting string*

How do we convert a decimal number to base-3 (like here) or base-62 [a-zA-z0-9] etc so the resulting number is not reversed without `strrev` and similar functions?

Comment: Are stdc functions like strtol not useful?  Or is this just a fun exercise?

Comment: @jimmcnamara, can `strtol` convert numbers to random bases with alphabets like `"dhowg"` or `"qwerty"`?

Comment: It can do for bases from 2 to 36. With conventional notation of 0-9A-Z

Comment: @EugeneSh., what about base-62 as mentioned in my question?

Comment: If you use uppercase letters you have base36 notation: 0-9 A-Z.  strtol supports that.  See: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html

Comment: It can't. You can read it's docs. Or it is a rhetorical question?

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by " didn't work for me" ?

Comment: You can pass in the the length of the output buffer and store characters from the end toward the front.  But why are you worrying about a call to `strrev()`?  How large are the numbers you're converting?

Comment: @EugeneSh., I mean, it didn't change anything.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, you see, I'm using `unsigned long long`.  The numbers I'm converting can be as big as 10^17 or something like that.

Comment: *"I don't know the size of the resulting string."* Why not allocate for the worst case of binary? A 64 bit int will require 66 bytes of string (if negative). That's not hugely wasteful.

Comment: @WeatherVane, that's what I'm doing. I suppose the length of this number won't go greater than 20. I've written this so people won't provide me with methods that require it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. take a function argument to say which of the 3 options - zero pad, space pad, no pad.

Comment: @WeatherVane I though first your comment is regarding the algorithm, but then realized that you are talking just about the allocation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, in response to OP recent edit.

Comment: Note `20` is too small.  Suggest `64+1` for a binary representation of a 64-bit number.

Comment: Allocating enough buffer for the result has nothing to do with whether or not there's a reason to avoid calling `strrev()` to keep things simple. As mentioned, the worst case number of digits in a result is around 64.  I'd suggest that it's probably not worth a whole lot to jump through hoops to avoid the `strrev()` on what's most likely too be much fewer than 64 characters per conversion call. I'd think that making sure you handle the buffer and/or allocation for the result correctly (and making for a simple interface) would be more worthwhile. But I haven't measured, so maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a parameter telling your function how much space it has to work with, populate the string backwards, and then return a pointer to the start of the created string.

```
char* No_Recursion(ull num, char *str, int base, char *alpha, size_t count){
    char *ptr = *str + count;

    *(ptr--) = `\0`;
    do{
        *(ptr--)=alpha[(num-1)%base];
        num=(num-1)/base;
    } while (num);

    return ptr;
}
```

Or, if you really want to have the string be stored in `str`, you can move back to the start, after you've calculated it.

```
void No_Recursion(ull num, char *str, int base, char *alpha, size_t count){
    char *ptr = *str + count;

    *(ptr--) = `\0`;
    do{
        *(ptr--)=alpha[(num-1)%base];
        num=(num-1)/base;
    } while (num);

    while(*ptr)
        *(str++) = *(ptr++);

    *ptr = '\0';
}
```

Note that both of these solutions, as well as both of the functions in the question, are **unsafe**.  All are succeptible to buffer overflows.  This can be solved in one of two ways:  keep track of where you are in the buffer, or be smart in how you allocate the buffer to ensure that it doesn't overflow.

Being smart about how you allocate space would involve performing computations before allocating the space.

```
int buffer_size = (int) ceil( log( t ) / log( sizeof(al)/sizeof(al[0]) )) );
char *s = calloc(buffer_size,sizeof(*s));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't include a very important thing in my most: edited it now. How do I know `size`? What if I say `size=5`, but the resulting string is 7 characters long? Will it work in this situation?

Comment: @ForceBru: `size` is the size of your buffer (20 in your original code), not the size of the string.  It is the maximum size of the string (converting a number that gives a longer string will overflow the buffer, casuing memory corruption and undefined behavior).  If you truly have unbounded potential strings, you'll need to realloc the buffer to be larger as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your "Recursion" function, such that each recursive call will return the "place" it was calculating for, so the current call will take this place and work for the next one:

```
int Recursion(ull num, char *str, int base, char*alpha) {
    if (!num) return -1;

    int place = 1 + Recursion((num-1)/base,str,base,alpha);
    *(str+place)=alpha[(num-1)%base];
    return place;
}
```

** And don't forget to deal with `\0` termination..
**Update**: Your `Recursion` implementation as well as the modified are not handling the case `num=0`. Both will just return unchanged `str`. This should be taken care of as well.